# How to transition a:links based on parent div :hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a menu on the lower left corner that I have several CSS3 transitions between a:link and a:hover inside this specific div including color, line-height, letter-spacing, and text-shadow. I also have a transition between div.floating-menu and div.floating-menu that affects line-height for the whole div, effectively collapsing this floating menu to the bottom of the page.

I have only links and h1 inside this div.

I want the menu to be collapsed and the links to be transparent (black works too) and then expand on hover over the div and make the links transition to opaque (or back to white).

I can't seem to get just the links to disappear when the menu collapses. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the HTML and CSS for the menu:

```
<div class="floating-menu">
<br /><br />
<a href="#">index</a>
<a href="#">search</a>
<a href="#">help</a>
<a href="#">members</a>
<a href="#">calendar</a>
<br /> 
<h1>menu</h1>
<br/>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.floating-menu {
position: fixed;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
width: 120px;
z-index: 100;
padding-left: 10px;
line-height: 0px;
transition: all 1s;
opacity: 1;
}
div.floating-menu:hover {
line-height: 9px;
opacity: 1;
}
div.floating-menu a, div.floating-menu h1 {
display: block;
margin: 0 0.5em;
}
div.floating-menu a:link, div.floating-menu a:visited {
color: #888888;
letter-spacing: -1px;
transition: all 1s;
text-shadow: 0 0 2px #cccccc;
opacity: 1;

}
div.floating-menu a:hover {
letter-spacing: 1px;
color: #ffffff;
color: #cccccc;
text-shadow: 0 0 2px #ffffff;
line-height: 13px;
}
div.floating-menu h1 {
color: #000000;
text-shadow: 0 0 25px #ffffff;
opacity: 1;
align: left;
}
```

Comment: you have typo here `align: left;`

Comment: This is **not** how you build a semantically logic menu! Use a `ul` with list-items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is jquery solution and working Demo -> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k4sd4/4/)**

```
$('.floating-menu').mouseover(function() {
  $('.floating-menu a').css("display","block");
 });


$('.floating-menu').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.floating-menu a').css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: That is fantastic! Thanks! Is there any way to make it fade when it appears and disappears?

Comment: Also, How do I implement this? I need to do it basically inline inside a pretty locked down editor...

Comment: Here is working demo with fadeIn/Out effects: http://jsfiddle.net/k4sd4/7/

Also I recommended you to use Jquery.
In this situation of your solution you can see that there are break downs in some cases when you hover the menu..with Jquery this will works perfectly.

In your html document, in the head tag you need to implement this script:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

and then you can open
`<script></script>` tag into your body and you can paste the jquery code from the Demo.

Here is the Jquery api, I hope this will help you:

http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

(CSS ONLY FIX) Added `opacity:0;` to `div.floating-menu a:link, div.floating-menu a:visited`and `opacity:1;` to `div.floating-menu:hover a:link, div.floating-menu a:visited`

```
div.floating-menu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 120px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 0px;
    transition: all 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
div.floating-menu:hover {
    line-height: 9px;
    opacity: 1;
}
div.floating-menu a, div.floating-menu h1 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
}
/*ADDED A '0 OPACITY'*/
div.floating-menu a:link, div.floating-menu a:visited {
    color: #888888;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    transition: all 1s;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #cccccc;
    opacity: 0;
}
/*ADDED A '1 OPACITY' ON MENU HOVER*/
div.floating-menu:hover a:link, div.floating-menu a:visited {
    opacity:1;
}
div.floating-menu a:hover {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #ffffff;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #ffffff;
    line-height: 13px;
}
div.floating-menu h1 {
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: 0 0 25px #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
    align: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Walery For The Clean Up, was too early in the morning for all that haha